# iText binary transparency bug

Tags: itext

I came accross the following problem embedding a transparent java.awt.Image into a pdf with iText (tried with 2.1.7 und 5.5.9).

I suppose iText does not handle binary transparent images correctly in this special case when converting them from ARGB Image to iText Image.

When the Image provided only contains 100% and 0% transparent pixels (i.e. binary transparency), and all the pixels are black (the opaqe and transparent ones - i.e. all pixel of the image have color=black but alpha value of 0% or 100%), the transparent pixel color value is internally detected as beeing black (this is wrong in my opinion), which leads to an invisble image in the generated pdf.

Test-Case:

```
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import com.itextpdf.text.BadElementException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Image;
import com.itextpdf.text.PageSize;
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

public class BinaryTransparencyBug {


    private static Image bkgnd;


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        bkgnd = Image.getInstance(new URL("http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext/sandbox/raw/master/resources/images/berlin2013.jpg"));
        bkgnd.scaleAbsolute(PageSize.A4);
        bkgnd.setAbsolutePosition(0, 0);


        Document document = new Document();
        File file = new File("target/binary_transparency_bug.pdf");
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, outputStream);
        document.open();


        addBackground(writer);
        document.add(new Paragraph("Binary transparency bug test case"));
        document.add(new Paragraph("OK: Visible image (opaque pixels are red, non opaque pixels are black)"));
        document.add(com.itextpdf.text.Image.getInstance(createBinaryTransparentAWTImage(Color.red,false,null), null));
        document.newPage();

        addBackground(writer);
        document.add(new Paragraph("Suspected bug: invisible image (both opaque an non opaque pixels have the same color)"));
        document.add(com.itextpdf.text.Image.getInstance(createBinaryTransparentAWTImage(Color.black,false,null), null));
        document.newPage();

        addBackground(writer);
        document.add(new Paragraph("Analysis: Aliasing makes the problem disappear, because this way the image is not binary transparent any more"));
        document.add(com.itextpdf.text.Image.getInstance(createBinaryTransparentAWTImage(Color.black,true,null), null));
        document.newPage();

        addBackground(writer);
        document.add(new Paragraph("Analysis: Setting the color of the transparent pixels to anything but black makes the problem go away, too"));
        document.add(com.itextpdf.text.Image.getInstance(createBinaryTransparentAWTImage(Color.black,false,Color.red), null));

        document.close();

    }

    private static void addBackground(PdfWriter writer)
            throws BadElementException, MalformedURLException, IOException, DocumentException {
        PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContentUnder();
        canvas.saveState();
        canvas.addImage(bkgnd);
        canvas.restoreState();
    }

    // Create an ARGB AWT Image that has only 100% transparent and 0%
    // transparent pixels.
    // All 100% opaque pixels have the provided color "color"
    // All transparent pixels have the Color "backgroundColor"
    public static BufferedImage createBinaryTransparentAWTImage(Color color, boolean alias, Color backgroundColor) {
        Dimension size = new Dimension(200, 200);
        BufferedImage awtimg = new BufferedImage(size.width, size.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g2d = awtimg.createGraphics();

        if (backgroundColor!=null)
        {
            //Usually it doen't make much sense to set the color of transparent pixels...
            //but in this case it changes the behavior of com.itextpdf.text.Image.getInstance fundamentally!
            g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC, 0f));       
            g2d.setColor(backgroundColor);
            g2d.fillRect(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
        }
        g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 1f));
        g2d.setColor(color);
        if (alias)
        {
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
        }

        BasicStroke bs = new BasicStroke(2);
        g2d.setStroke(bs);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            g2d.drawLine((size.width + 2) / 4 * i, 0, (size.width + 2) / 4 * i, size.height - 1);
            g2d.drawLine(0, (size.height + 2) / 4 * i, size.width - 1, (size.height + 2) / 4 * i);
        }
        return awtimg;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my proposal for the fix of the problem:

in Image.getInstance(AWTImage,color,forcebw):
in the case forceBW=false and color=null:

```
for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
    byte alpha = smask[j] = (byte) (pixels[j] >> 24 & 0xff);
    /* bugfix by Chris Nokleberg */
    if (!shades) {
        if (alpha != 0 && alpha != -1) { 
            //as soon as there is any pixel with alpha not 0% or 100%
            //switch to smask
            shades = true;
        } else if (transparency == null) {
            //in binary transparency mode, determine the transparentPixel Color to be the 
            //value of the first Pixel we find with 100% transparency
            if (alpha == 0) {
                transparentPixel = pixels[j] & 0xffffff;
                transparency = new int[6];
                transparency[0] = transparency[1] = transparentPixel >> 16 & 0xff;
                transparency[2] = transparency[3] = transparentPixel >> 8 & 0xff;
                transparency[4] = transparency[5] = transparentPixel & 0xff;
                // vvv--- added by mkl
                // Check whether this value for transparent pixels
                // has already been used for a non-transparent one
                // before this position
                for (int jj = 0; jj < j; jj++)
                {
                    if ((pixels[jj] & 0xffffff) == transparentPixel)
                    {
                        // found a prior use of the transparentPixel color
                        // and, therefore, cannot make use of this color
                        // for transparency; we could still use an image
                        // mask but for simplicity let's use a soft mask
                        // which already is implemented here
                        shades = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                // ^^^--- added by mkl
            }
        } else if (((pixels[j] & 0xffffff) != transparentPixel) && (alpha==0)) {
            //TB: The above if seems incorrect to me. (EDIT: it was if ((pixels[j] & 0xffffff) != transparentPixel)
            //As soon as we find any pixel that has differnt color from  
            //transparentPixel-Color and alpha 0% or 100% 
            //switch of binary transparency mode.
            //IMHO this should only be done if alpha==0!
            //so the if clause should be 
            //((pixels[j] & 0xffffff) != transparentPixel) && (alpha==0)
            shades = true;
        }
        //TB: Proposed fix:
        else if ((pixels[j] & 0xffffff) == transparentPixel && alpha!=0) {
            //switch of binary transparency mode, if we find any pixel with the transparentPixel-Color,
            //but which is not transparent 
            shades = true;
        }                       
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Could you submit this as a pull request on the GitHub repo? That's the recommended place to submit your patch. http://github.com/itext/itextpdf

Comment: That been said, the solution is not complete.

Comment: The proposal in comments (!) correctly proposes to differentiate between  the `alpha == 0` and `alpha == -1` situation but it does not yet check that the `transparentPixel` has not been used  *before* `transparentPixel` was determined.

Comment: As long as transparentPixel is not yet initialized, we will always enter the "else if (transparency == null)". So the value is not used before beeing initialized. @mkl Do you agree with that? I've added the original code that makes clear, that transparentPixel and transparency are linked.

Comment: *Do you agree with that?* - Of course we always enter that block before `transparentPixel` initialization. And that only underlines the issue I meant. Before the `transparentPixel` is determined in the first pixel with transparency, it obviously cannot be verified that prior pixels have a different color. Thus, the code right after setting the `transparentPixel` value must additionally check that this value has not yet been used in prior (non-transparent) pixels. Otherwise a simple variation of your own sample code will result in an error.

Comment: I added the missing check to your proposal. By the way, using *xor* (`^`) you could easily shorten the final two `else if`s into a single one: `else if (((pixels[j] & 0xffffff) == transparentPixel) ^ (alpha == 0)) { shades = true; }`